# Mail Confirmation sent Probl

Tags: forms, email, web

Sorry for the English.
Hi, I'm lost and I can't find the error. On a web page I have a form for the reader to enter their email address and press the send button. The only thing I need is for the confirmation that this person has put her identification email to reach my email, so I know that she is interested. The problem is that I don't get any notifications to my personal email. Where this error?

```
       <button class="button-send" id="send-button">
            <span class="button-text">
                ENVIAR
            </span>
        </button>
        <span class="input-description" style="display: none;" id="text-confirm">
            Gracias. Enseguida nos pondremos en contacto con usted.
        </span>
        <script>
            var sendButton = document.getElementById("send-button");
            sendButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                var input = document.getElementById("email");
                var value = input.value;
                if (value != "") {
                    const form = new FormData();
                    form.append('from', value);
                    form.append('to', 'joselm65@gmail.com');
                    form.append('subject', `${userName} está interesado en GPT Care`);
                    form.append('text', `${userName} con email ${value} está interesado en GPT Care`);

                    fetch('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox5759acc5026845d88c92b60e1045d717.mailgun.org/messages', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('api:9c422337978d994def393a88ba9ab619-181449aa-822aa8ea')
                    },
                    body: form
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        input.value = "";
                        const text = document.getElementById("text-confirm");
                        text.style.display = "block";
                    });
                }
            });
```